# pgfplots error plot 3D math function of two variables

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I want to plot a very typical production function (q=L^0.5*K^0.5) in 3D using pgfplots package. When I compile the following MVE I get the following error "! Package pgfplots Error: An internal error occured during z buffer reorderings: the rows/cols where not balanced! I have rows= 25, cols=25. If this happens to be wrong, you might want to provide rows and cols manually.."

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title={prueba},xlabel=$L$,ylabel=$K$,small]
\addplot3[surf]{x^(0.5) * y^(0.5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The default domain in PGFPlots runs from -5 to 5, so you'll get some non-real results. Set `domain=0:5, y domain=0:5` (for example), and it'll work

Comment: I had already tried it but the error remained the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default domain in PGFPlots runs from -5 to 5, so you'll get some non-real results. Set `domain=0:5, y domain=0:5` (for example), and it'll work

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3[surf, domain=0:5, y domain=0:5]{x^(0.5) * y^(0.5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had also a problem because the pgfplots package was not updated :-( my mistake!