# pgfplots error ploting function of two variables

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I want to plot `$f(x,y) = \sqrt{y - x^{2}}$` but I get the  following error:

*!Package pgfplots internal Error: An internal error ocurred during z buffer reorderings: the rows/cols are not balanced! I have rows = 25, cols = 25.*

The code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ymin = 0,
            xmin = -4,
            xmax = 4,
            zmin = 0,
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
            zlabel = {$f(x,y)$},
            colormap/cool
            ]
        \addplot3[
            surf,
            domain = -4:4,
            ]{sqrt(y - x^2)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Gráfico de $f(x,y) = \sqrt{y - x^{2}}$.}
    \label{fig:sqrty-x2}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Your example with pgfplots loaded and `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` (without "english" option in documentclass) works fine in overleaf .... Please share your latex version. (Welcome to TeX.SE!)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome! A very similar error was reported [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237125), and I think the solution proposed in [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237127) will work here, too. It needs, however, slightly different, a simple domain change will not work (in this basis). One option is to add

```
restrict expr to domain={y-x*x}{0:100}
```

other options include filters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}% <-added but not necessary
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ymin = 0,
            xmin = -4,
            xmax = 4,
            zmin = 0,
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
            zlabel = {$f(x,y)$},
            colormap/cool,
            restrict expr to domain={y-x*x}{0:100}
            ]
        \addplot3[
            surf,
            domain = -4:4,
            ]{sqrt(y - x*x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Gr\'afico de $f(x,y) = \sqrt{y - x^{2}}$.}
    \label{fig:sqrty-x2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Yet another option is to change the function that gets plotted to `sqrt(max(y - x*x,0))`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}% <-added but not necessary
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ymin = 0,
            xmin = -2.5,
            xmax = 2.5,
            zmin = 0,
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
            zlabel = {$f(x,y)$},
            colormap/cool,
            ]
        \addplot3[
            surf,
            domain = -2:2,
            domain y=0:4
            ]{sqrt(max(y - x^2,0))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Gr\'afico de $f(x,y) = \sqrt{y - x^{2}}$.}
    \label{fig:sqrty-x2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I also changed the domains a bit.